# React UseEffect - Executing only when data is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I know Functions passed to useEffect are executed on every component rendering, i am in a situation where i need `useEffect` hook not run on initial render but only when these data are rendered => `home.matchsPlayed, home.winHome`

This is my actual situation

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setData(prev =>
      prev.concat([
        {
          day: home.matchsPlayed,
          [selectedHomeName]: home.winHome
        }
      ])
    );
  },[home.matchsPlayed, home.winHome, selectedHomeName]);

  console.log('data', [data]);
```

Data array looks like this

[image]

I have seen a solution where i can make use of `useRef` to keep track of `initialMount` with `useEffect`

So i changed to

```
const isInitialMount = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInitialMount.current) {
       isInitialMount.current = undefined;
    } else {
      setData(prev =>
        prev.concat([
          {
            day: home.matchsPlayed,
            [selectedHomeName]: hhome.winHome
          }
        ])
      );
    }
  },[home.matchsPlayed, home.winHome, selectedHomeName]);
```

The array has now 1 object less undefined which is slightly better

[image]

I want my `data` `array` being like this, without the first 3 objects undefined because the data are not presented in the initial renderings. **How can i achieve it?**

```
  Data: [
    {day:22, Sao Paulo: -8},
    {day:16, Sao Paulo: -2},
    {day:27,  Sao Paulo: -9}
  ],
```

I have reproduced the case here => https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-wind-sism9 (In order to see the demo a chrome extension to unblock the CORS has to be installed, i use CORS Unblock)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!home.matchsPlayed || !home.totalCal || !selectedHomeName) {
      return;
    }

    setData(prev =>
      prev.concat([
        {
          day: home.matchsPlayed,
          [selectedHomeName]: home.totalCal
        }
      ])
    );
  },[home.matchsPlayed, home.totalCal, selectedHomeName]);
```

Wouldn't that do it?

Comment: Thanks, this is actually the output with your solution 0: {day: undefined, "": undefined}
1: {day: undefined, "": undefined}
2: {day: undefined, São Paulo: undefined}
3: {day: 16, São Paulo: -2}
4: {day: 16, São Paulo: -2}
5: {day: 22, São Paulo: -8}
6: {day: 22, São Paulo: -8}
7: {day: 27, São Paulo: -9}
8: {day: 27, São Paulo: -9}